# Is there a way to pass the value of one DateTime object to another without them referencing the same object?

Tags: c#, datetime, reference

I'm trying to create a program that outputs an itinerary, but I'm having issues with finding a way around my two `DateTime` objects pointing towards the same object. A specific `DateTime` is passed as an argument into the method and I use two other `DateTime` object within the method (which both currently point to the argument)

None of my normal fixes like `memberwiseClone()` work for `DateTime`, so I'm at a bit of a loss.

```
{
    DateTime1 = x;
    for (int i = 0; i < someArray.Length; i++)
    {
        DateTime2 = DateTime1;
        double minutes = someValue / someOtherValue;
        DateTime2.AddMinutes(minutes);
        WriteLine("{0:hh//:mm} ---> {1:hh//:mm}, item #{2}", DateTime1, DateTime2, i);
        DateTime1 = DateTime2;
    }
}
```

I would ideally like it to print out something along the lines of:

```
"21:00 ---> 21:30, item #1"
"21:30 ---> 22:00, item #2"
```

However, at the moment I'm just getting all values at the initial value of the `DateTime` argument.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here, `DateTime` is a value type, which means it contains the value entirely, it does not reference a common object. Basically, in your code here you have 3 DateTime values, `x`, `DateTime1`, and `DateTime2`, these are separate. Changing one does not change another. Can you please clarify what the problem is?

Comment: Please familiarize with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057267/what-is-the-difference-between-a-reference-type-and-value-type-in-c

Comment: What output do you get instead of the desired output?

Comment: Thanks for your help, an answer below gave me the fix. Don't know why I thought DateTime was an object instead of  a value type, but guess that's all part of learning to code.

Answer (score 1):

`System.DateTime` struct is **immutable** which means it could not be changed.
Its methods like `AddMinutes` are not changing the value of the original structure, but it has a return value that contains a value that is the result of the specified operation.

You should use `DateTime2 = DateTime1.AddMinutes(minutes)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your input, this ended up being the issue with my code.

Answer (score 0):

The line `DateTime2.AddMinutes(minutes);` is not `void`, it returns the result. Change it to:

```
DateTime2 = DateTime1.AddMinutes(minutes);
```

Comment: Thank-you for your help, this was the issue.